# Queues getting dequeued automatically in activemq

Tags: activemq-classic

I am facing a specific problem in activemq.
If my REST consumer is not closed properly the messages are getting dequeued automatically and the messages are getting lost.
Is there any way i can close the session with closing the browser.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arijit

Comment: could you be a bit more specific? You have a Consumer that is exposed as a REST Web Service? Some code would not hurt at all to answer your question.